# glGetError() returned the following error codes after a call to glEnableVertexAttribArray(<int> 0xFFFFFFFF): GL_INVALID_VALUE

Tags: opengl

This is the stacktrace ..

```
com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] glGetError() returned the following error codes after a call to glEnableVertexAttribArray(<int> 0xFFFFFFFF): GL_INVALID_VALUE ( 1281 0x501), 
    at com.jogamp.opengl.DebugGL4bc.writeGLError(DebugGL4bc.java:30672)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.DebugGL4bc.glEnableVertexAttribArray(DebugGL4bc.java:4921)
```

In object's draw() ..

```
float[] color = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};

// enable glsl
gl2.glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

// enable alpha
gl2.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);
gl2.glBlendFunc(GL.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

// Set color for drawing
setmColorHandle(gl2.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "vColor"));
gl2.glUniform4fv(getmColorHandle(), 1, color, 0);

// get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
mPositionHandle = gl2.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vPosition");

// Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
gl2.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
```

vertex shader ..

```
#version 120

uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
attribute vec4 vPosition;

void main() {
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

fragment shader ..

```
#version 120

uniform vec4 vColor;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vColor;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your vertex shader you don't use the `vPosition` attribute anywhere, so the driver will most likely optimize it away when compiling. That means that `glGetAttribLocation` will not return a valid value, which means that `glEnableVertexAttribArray` will fail. Change your vertex shader to actually use the `uMVPMatrix` and `vPosition` variables that you are declaring, i.e:

```
uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
attribute vec4 vPosition;

void main() {
    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;
}
```

Make sure you actually pass in a value for `uMVPMatrix` (it's not clear whether you do so later in your code).